# he says I'll _______ get better

Tags: idiomatic-language

*I'm not good at math. But my teacher says **I'll get better** if I just keep doing my best.*

What would be the most natural way to make the bold-face part sound a little more assuring from the teacher's part? All I can come up with is to insert *certainly*, but would something be more idiomatic?

Comment: 'Surely' is quite reassuring, 'probably' less so.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of word you are looking for could either be '*definitely*' or '*certainly*'. But your statement is conditional - you will only get better **if** you try. While there's nothing wrong with saying something will *definitely* happen *if* a condition is met, your sentence doesn't really need it.

The problem I see with your sentence is this - how can you get better by doing your best? You can't get better than best.

I think you need to say:

> I'm not good at math, but my teacher says I'll definitely get better if I *keep practising*.

Practice makes perfect!